# How to add space and $ in front of column in django-tables2

Tags: django, django-models, django-tables2

I have two dollar columns in my django table, however, I don't like the spacing and the fact that it's right next to the preceding column. I also want to add a dollar symbol. How can I add this?

Right now it looks like this:

```
Price1Price2
345.09 154.35
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
Price1    Price2
$345.09   $154.35
```

My django table is basic:

```
class PriceTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Price
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        sequence = ('service', 'price1', 'price2')
        exclude = ("comments")
        attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

Those columns are defined like this in models.py:

```
price1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
price2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
```

One futher question, is there a django-tables2 table description function or something to easily add info about the table, under the table?

This code is based on Dan's great answer! He got it to work with data from the same table with this code:

```
class Price1Column(tables.Column):
  def render(self, record):
      return ' ${}'.format(record.price1)
```

Now I want a column from another table - Service, but this does not work:

```
class Price2Column(tables.Column):
  def render(self, record):
      return ' ${}'.format(record.tables.Column(accessor='service.price2'))
  class Meta:
      model = Price
```

Here is the model for service, it connects to Price through code. The tables.Column(acessor=) line works in the Class PriceTable().

```
class Service(models.Model):
    serviceid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
    desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key = True)
    code = models.IntegerField(default= 10000)
    price2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['serviceid']

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.desc_us
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html) I assume this is how you do it:

```
class Price1Column(tables.Column):

    def render(self, record):
        return '${}'.format(record.price1)

class Price2Column(tables.Column):

    def render(self, record):
        return '${}'.format(record.price2)

class PriceTable(tables.Table):
    # ...
    price1 = Price1Column()
    price2 = Price2Column()
```

Comment: @JR The last two lines should go in your `PriceTable` class

Comment: I'm not sure if you would know this,but how might I add a column from another model. I added a little code above.

Comment: @JR Added where?

Comment: Sorry, just added.

Comment: @JR Add the model for that field too

Comment: Added the service model

Comment: @JR Need to see how they are related. And why are you using a text field as primary key?

Comment: the foreign key is code an integer field. The primary key is desc_us a text field.

Comment: `desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key = True)`

Comment: Sorry yes, edited the foreign key is code and primary key is decs_us a text field.